# Sqlite-net linq GroupBy cannot be translated

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sqlite-net

I am using Xamarin c# linq with sqlite-net pcl (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). I found that all my linq groupby cannot be properly translated into SQL. Linq translates the Where clause but not Group By.

In the following example, the fields used in Transaction:

```
AccountId: int
Amount: double
ICategoryId: int
```

All these query formats result in SQL without Group By:

```
select * from "Transaction" where ("DateWithoutTime" <= ?)

var accountBalances1 = _dataService.Connection.Table<Transaction>()
    .Where(r => r.DateWithoutTime <= displayDuration.DurationEnd)
    .GroupBy(r => r.AccountId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Balance = g.Sum(b => b.Amount)
    })
    .ToList();

var accountBalances2 = _dataService.Connection.Table<Transaction>()
   .Where(r => r.DateWithoutTime <= displayDuration.DurationEnd)
   .GroupBy(r => r.AccountId,
    (key, g) => new
    {
        Id = key,
        Balance = g.Sum(b => b.Amount),
    })
    .ToList();

var accountBalances3 = (from t in _dataService.Connection.Table<Transaction>()
                        where t.DateWithoutTime <= displayDuration.DurationEnd
                        group t by t.AccountId
                        into g
                        select new { g.Key, Balance = g.Sum(g => g.Amount) })
                       .ToList();
```

To clarify it has nothing to do with double data type, I tried another group by with int data type only:

```
var maxIECategoryId = _dataService.Connection.Table<Transaction>()
   .Where(r => r.DateWithoutTime <= displayDuration.DurationEnd)
   .GroupBy(r => r.AccountId,
    (key, g) => new
    {
        Id = key,
        IECategoryId = g.Max(b => b.IECategoryId)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Similarly, the generated sql does not have group by.

All group by are processed locally. Is there any trick to write a linq group by that can be processed on the server service? or it is a limitation of this implementation of sqlite orm?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: The source code says "A queryable object that is able to translate Where, OrderBy, and Take queries into native SQL." `GroupBy` does not appear to be supported, so you would have to switch to client side evaluation by putting `AsEnumerable()` before the `GroupBy` call.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks. After looked at the source code, I found that I am too naive to count on the simple orm.

Comment: @Nick The problem is not with sqlite-net that is a light, very simple and efficient Code-First ORM. You work with Lists. You read tables or SQLite queries to get lists, you update db from lists, you insert and delete in db while mainaining lists, unless using the sqlite-net-extensions that is very slow on large foreigns. That's all. Some things must be done manually but it's not much compared to the gain on simple apps. If there is a problem with groupby it is with the code on the .net generic lists itself. I'm not advanced in groupby and had not read your code, thus I can't help more, sorry.

Comment: @nick In other words, using sqlite-net, you work with LINQ-to-objects, not LINQ-toSQL. No SQLite SQL query is generated while using LINQ on sqlite-net. That its power and its blemish. And I really like to use it with the BindingListView.